# JBOSS Rest service 404 helloworld

Tags: eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am trying to run a basic restful service in eclipse with jboss. I run the program on the jboss 7 server and I then send a get request through the chrome extension postman. using the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/SIMSWEB/MyRESTApplication
```

Except I always get a 404 error response, My web.xml file and service files seem in order so Im unsure what the problem is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HelloWorldSerice file:

```
package com.sims.webservices;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import com.sims.model.business.Parentbean;

@Path("/MyRESTApplication")
public class HelloWorldResource {


@Inject
private Parentbean subjectbean;


@GET()
@Produces("text/plain")
public String sayHello() {

    return "Hello World!";
}
}
```

And here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>SIMSWEB</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
<param-value>org.jboss.samples.rs.webservices.MyRESTApplication</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what exactly the problem is but I got it working for you. I have shared the war file

[SIMSWEB.war](http://www.filedropper.com/simswebwar)

You may want to check your libraries and org.jboss.samples.rs.webservices.MyRESTApplication java file.

By the way, upon the deployment I could access

```
http://localhost:8080/SIMSWEB/MyRESTApplication
```

and see "Hello World!"